# Advanced Developer Certification Changes

Tags: developer, certification

I am aware that there will be a new roadmap for the developer certification process. Has anyone heard any updates? Currently working on my advanced dev cert and wondering if I should hold for more info.

Comment: me too! They are changing certificate names and new question are being designed by well known stars.

Comment: Top secret source says wait on the Adv. Cert until the new ones come out!

Comment: Why wait! Pass it and also give the new one as well. Get the 2x.

Comment: Why wait, might be because of the cost and the intense preparation and work required... are they going to honor the old one still once the new ones roll out?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [question](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1997/changes-to-the-advanced-developer-certification) I've posted on Salesforce StackExchange Meta. Also have a look at this [information](http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/FAQ-New-App-Builder-and-Platform-Developer-Credentials) in Salesforce's Knowledge Base.

It might answer some of your questions. I, for example am in a peculiar scenario where I was able to register for the multiple choice exam and passed it and now I don't know how to continue with the rest of the steps. Will the programming assignment be under the new certification, will it be under the old one, do I need to take any transition exam. These are the sort of questions I have and I guess the best option is to wait and see any announcements at Dreamforce in September.

I've logged a support case with Salesforce Certification and will update this answer as soon as I get a response from them

**UPDATE**

Just received a reply from Salesforce after raising a case with their certification team and it says:

> We are sincerely sorry for the delays [...]. We had planned on
>   announcing an update by the end of June; however [...] We are
>   currently implementing a plan for eligible candidates to complete the
>   programming assignment. We will announce complete details in
>   mid-August

I guess is the same answer as we had before, we just have to wait and see.

Comment: Thanks Mihai, I am in a similar conundrum! I have seen that info too... I guess we will have to wait and see! I bet they will be fair about it <3

Comment: And I was thinking that I'm the only one! It's a bit daft with the fact that they still let you register for the multiple choice exam even though they are changing the entire certification.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

They've just announced information about the transition process, including the process for people who have passed the multiple choice part of Advanced Developer.

Full details are here http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/FAQ-Developer-Certification-Transition-Process